# Evaluate if a shiny app input is not empty not working, how to do it right?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shinny app and with a numeric input and I initiate its value in the UI like empty, I am trying to evaluate if this value is not empty then do something but it not working

this is how I initiate on the UI

```
numericInput("Max_Risk", label="Max Risk", value="")
```

when a button is pressed

I assign its value to a variable

```
max_risk = input$Max_Risk
```

then I have an if condition that evaluates the value of max_risk

```
if (max_risk != ""){
dat2 <- dplyr::filter(dat2, coe_var < max_risk)
                }
```

when there is a value on the input, lets say the number 86, it does work and gets into the of statement and continues with the code, but when there is no value in the input, i.e is left blank I get this error

```
Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I need that if the input is left blank then don't do the if statement and continue with the code, any help thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juan

Maybe it is NA value at the begining. Try:

```
if (!is.na(max_risk) && max_risk != ""){
dat2 <- dplyr::filter(dat2, coe_var < max_risk)
                }
```

> Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed usually means that you are trying to evaluate a variable which is a NA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "empty" you mean the object has not be created, you could use `exists` like so:

```
if (exists("max_risk") && max_risk != ""){
    dat2 <- dplyr::filter(dat2, coe_var < max_risk)
    }
```

If `max_risk` is an object, then `exists("max_risk")` will return `TRUE`. The `&&` evaluates the left expression first and only evaluates the right expression if the left is found to be `TRUE`. So if an object doesn't exist, then `max_risk != ""` won't be evaluated.